# Testing if some process has missing data

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, missing-data

I am studying a time process, consisting in events occuring at some dates, one after the other (typically one event every 1-2 days, sometimes several in a day, with data covering circa 20 years). I would like to test if there are some events that are missing in the series I handle. Do you see some method I could apply to do so?

My original idea was to assume that the complete series (i.e. when "adding" the missing data) is the result of a Poisson process and to try to see if the "holes" make the process deviate from this assumption. But I am not sure it does make sense. Any idea?

Edit: here is the distribution of the time difference between consecutive events, in days.
[image: histogram of date diffs]

Comment: You should enquire about the time intervals on which the observations are recorded/missing. Without this information you can not estimate the rate of a Poisson process. Moreover severe biases may occur if it turns out that missingness relates to the variable of interest.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at this

Comment: When you write "I would like to test if there are some events that are missing," do you mean events that occurred but were not recorded?  Also, could you show here a histogram of the time delay between events?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. Some events occurred but we do not have trace of them. I have edited the question to include the distribution of the differences between dates of recorded events (in days). Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think I guess what you have in mind: if I assume my process to be a Poisson process, the time diffs have an exponential law. So testing if some events are missing would amount to test if the time diffs follow indeed this law. Is it the idea?

Comment: Although it *might* work, it's probably not a very powerful method.  You're far better off studying how the gaps are associated with the time.

Comment: Like using time series methods on the time difference between events?